# Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure in jenkins

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

Hi I'm running selenium script via Git-lab, and Git-lab is correctly configured with Jenkins in Freestyle Project. I am using window machine so i have used "Execute Window Batch Command" in Build option. so this is the which i have configured in this

```
set Path=\Python_Home\;%PATH%
Python C:/Users/mindz/PycharmProjects/Mindz/CPP_Project/Cpp_login.py
```

So this error is displaying after running the build.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\cpp_test>exit

1. Build step `Execute Windows batch command` marked build as failure"

Comment: Jenkins marks the build status based on the return code of the batch command you are executing. For Jenkins to mark a build as passed, the exit code should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to help you without access to the '.py' script.

Several advices:

1. Check that all paths with the space symbol are enclosed in quotation
   marks. Maybe you have something related to this because there is a
   space symbol on the path to the workspace.
2. You could use an absolute path to the job workspace without the space symbol.